# Azure Media Services Strange Behaviour (ApplyIntelligenceCommand.)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services, azure-blob-storage

Yesterday, I had setup Azure Media Services to upload an asset from stream.

It was working the day before and today. However now it stopped working it is giving me weird errors, that I cannot find answers for online.

Could it be that `Upload(Stream stream)` from the `IAssetFile` class is down?

Here is my code:

```
foreach (var content in provider.Contents) 
{
    // Upload as an asset to Azure Media services
    IAsset asset = await _service.CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile(content, "Input Asset");
}
```

Here is my `CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile` function:

```
public async Task<IAsset> CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile(HttpContent content, string assetName, AssetCreationOptions options = AssetCreationOptions.None)
{
        IAsset asset = _context.Assets.Create(assetName, options);
        Console.WriteLine(content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);

        IAssetFile assetFile = await asset.AssetFiles.CreateAsync("love.mp4", CancellationToken.None);

        if (content != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("creating stream");

            using (Stream stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Uploading to blob storage");
                assetFile.Upload(stream);
                return asset;
            }
        }
        return asset;
}
```

Here are the errors that I am getting

> Error: ErrorProcessingTask. An error has occurred.
> Stage: ApplyIntelligenceCommand.
> Code: 0xBEBBB1B7
>
> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invalid data found when processing input
> Microsoft.Media.Encoding.Common.Commands.CommandLineException: An error has occurred while executing a command.

What I am thinking is that the `Upload(Stream stream)` stopped working for some reason.

When I upload a video locally and then run face redactor everything works perfectly fine.

But when I upload through the stream it doesn't work anymore.

Additionally, when I check my blob storage to verify if the image or video is there and that it works, it is actually uploaded correctly.

So I am confused why Media services is giving the above errors.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I will answer this issue myself,

The problem was with the version of `windowsazure.mediaservices` and `windowsazure.mediaservices.extenstions` I had version 4.1.0.1 installed and it was not correctly uploading the stream.

However on version 4.1.0.0 it is correctly uploading all videos and images.

Comment: Still seeing this same issue with 4.2.0.0. Downgrading to 4.1.0.0 fixed the problem.